# Using vue-meta with computed properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-meta

I'm trying to add dynamic meta tags to my article page. Articles are stored in a VueX store and I use a computed property to get the article I want to display :

```
computed: {
  article() {
   return this.$store.state.articles.filter(article => article.id == this.$route.params.id);
  }
}
```

I am using vue-meta for this (is there a better way to do it? I'm not using Nuxt so I don't have server side rendering).

The correct way to use it would be :

```
metaInfo() {
  return {
    title: this.article.title,

    meta: [
     {property: 'og:title', content: this.article.title},
     {property: 'og:site_name', content: 'Website Name'},
     {property: 'og:type', content: 'website'},
     {property: 'og:url', content: 'url.com'},
     {property: 'og:image', content: this.article.image},
     {property: 'og:description', content: this.article.description},
     ]
   }
 }
```

But it only works if the article is stored in `data()`. Since the component return dynamic articles, how can I access the filtered article in the computed property?

Thank you for you help

Answer (score 1):

You need to name your computed property as `article`, also thanks to @ssc-hrep2 use `find` instead of `filter` to return the matched object in an array, since `filter` returns an array:

```
computed: {
  article () {
    return this.$store.state.articles.find(article => article.id == this.$route.params.id)
  }
}
```

Or use `mapState` from `vuex`:

```
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

computed: mapState({
  article: state => state.articles.find(article => article.id == this.$route.params.id)
})
```

Comment: I did it, i just misspelled it I will edit thank you

Comment: @Psidom I'm using vue-meta to dynamically update application/ld+json for "google rich card" I can see it on inspecting elements wondering is there a way we can update the same on the view-source Thanks